# extract a _m128 variable to float

Tags: x86, sse, simd

```
float myfunction ( P b1, P b2, int dimention )
{       
    __m128 v_b1,v_b2,v_b3;
    int j=0;

    for (int i=0; i<dimention/4; i++) {
        v_b1=_mm_load_ps(b1.c +j);
        v_b2=_mm_load_ps(b2.c +j);
        v_b3=_mm_sub_ps(v_b1,v_b2);
        j+=4;   
    }
}
```

What I'm really trying to do is this:

```
for (int i=0; i<dimention; i++ ) {
    result += b1.c[i] - b2.c[i];
}
```

I want to return `result`. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to sum all the differences and then return this as the function result:

```
#include <pmmintrin.h>                   // SSE3

float myfunction ( P b1, P b2, int dimention )
{       
    __m128 v_b1, v_b2, v_b3, v_b4;
    float f;

    v_b4 = _mm_setzero_ps();             // initialise sum of differences to zero
    for (int j = 0; j < dimention; j += 4)
    {
        v_b1 = _mm_load_ps(b1.c + j);    // load 4 floats from b1[j]
        v_b2 = _mm_load_ps(b2.c + j);    // load 4 floats form b2[j]
        v_b3 = _mm_sub_ps(v_b1, v_b2);   // calc 4 differences
        v_b4 = _mm_add_ps(v_b4, v_b3);   // accumulate 4 differences
    }
    v_b4 = _mm_hadd_ps(v_b4, v_b4);      // sum horizontally
    v_b4 = _mm_hadd_ps(v_b4, v_b4);      // (NB: need to do this twice to sum all 4 elements)
    _mm_store_ss(&f, v_b4);              // extract sum
    return f;                            // return sum
}
```

If this is not what you're trying to do then please update your question with more details and I'll update the code accordingly.

Comment: I edited my question...by the way i get this error ‘_mm_hadd_ps’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: OK - I think my solution works for you then - note that `_mm_hadd_ps` is SSE3, so you need to `#include <pmmintrin.h>`.

Comment: Thank you very much i think it works! When i return f; i get a segmentation fault.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: The only possible cause I can see for a seg fault with the above code would be if either b1.c or b2.c is not correctly aligned (they both need to be 16 byte aligned). If that's not the problem then you will need to investigate further and perhaps post a new question.